# getReactions() returns empty list, regardless of the amount of reactions

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

When I try to read the reactions added to a message sent I'm always getting an empty list.

```
        MessageBuilder mb = new MessageBuilder();

        channel.sendMessage(mb.build()).queue((t);
```

After adding reactions to it, I execute this code:

```
        System.out.println(t.getReactions().size());

        for (MessageReaction r : t.getReactions()) {
            System.out.println(r.getReactionEmote().getName());
        }
```

(this is yet to be implemented, I'm just trying to get to understand how I can use it)

I am expecting the output to be the amount of reactions I added, yet `System.out.println(t.getReactions().size());` will always print 0 regardless of the amount of reactions added to the message sent.

Furthermore, when iterating of the list containing reactions, it always won't print anything to the console, since the list seems to be empty.

Is there something I need to add that I can use `.getReactions()`?

What I also tried is using an eventWaiter:

```
eventWaiter.waitForEvent(GuildMessageReactionAddEvent.class, (event) -> {

        return "".equals(event.getReactionEmote().getName()) && !event.getUser().isBot()
                    && event.getMessageIdLong() == messageId;

        }, (event) -> {

            System.out.println("Reacting to reaction");

        }, (long) 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS, () -> {

            System.out.println("Timeout. No event was registered.");

        });
```

This always outputs the timeout warning, regardless of reactions added.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how JDA works.
The reactions do not get magically updated, you can get the reactions by [fetching the message](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html#retrieveMessageById(long)) or by listening for the [reaction add event](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/events/message/guild/react/GuildMessageReactionAddEvent.html).

To use the event waiter properly you must make sure that the same instance is also registered on JDA by using `JDABuilder#addEventListeners`.

So either listen for the event manually or make sure that you only use once instance of the `EventWaiter` class in your code that is also registered on the JDA builder.